# Функция copy и set

Tags: c++, stl

Мне нужно переместить list в set, я думал что для этого можно использовать функцию copy, но все оказалось не так просто, так как у класса set нету метода push_back, и написать так я не могу:

```
copy(myList.begin(), myList.end(), back_inserter(mySet));
```

Есть ли что-то аналогичное функции copy для set-а? Или эту функцию надо писать как-то по-другому? Подскажите пожалуйста, буду признателен.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функция `std::copy` не виновата. Проблема в том, что вы использовали `std::back_inserter`. Как вы сами заметили, `std::back_inserter` с `std::set` работать не умеет.

С `std::set` следует использовать `std::inserter`, если уж вам хочется воспользоваться именно `std::copy`.

Comment: Либо так `mySet.insert(myList.begin(), myList.end());`

Comment: Большое спасибо)